# Copy lines text from file with tab characters

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL command to create a table from a text file.

SQL Command:

```
create table hba ( lines text);
copy hba from 'C:/ProgramData/PostgreSQL/10/pg_hba.conf'
```

Works great until the text file contains a tab character.

When the text file contains a tab character, I get an error:

> ERROR [22P04] ERROR: extra data after last expected column;

So the tab is acting as delimiter of some kind that I would just like to ignore and treat like any character.

Comment: You can change the default tab delimiter by specifying another character as the delimiter.

Comment: So in my case, I don't want a delimiter at all.  I want my table to have one column.  So do I have to choose a delimiter that I know will never occur in my file?

Comment: Yes, I believe you need to choose something that will never appear in the line.

Comment: Yes, this works, thank-you.  But seems maybe unreliable if the character I choose does happen to be present in the file.

Comment: @Peter yes, it would be nice if you could set the delimiter to be NULL, but no one has implemented that.